# Mono tlstest.exe error

Tags: c#, asp.net, https, mono

## Setting up Mono for ASP.net app dev on a MacBook Pro El Capitan 10.11.12 i5: tlstest.cs compiles with 3 warnings, and tlstest.exe compiles with 1 error

### Attempting to run the tests outlined here:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/mono-basics/

```
mono hello.exe //runs fine with no errors and prints "Hello Mono World"
```

However, I downloaded tlstest.cs(see link above for source) and compiled it with:

```
mcs tlstest.cs /r:System.dll /r:Mono.Security.dll
```

**This returned 3 warnings as follows:**

*tlstest.cs(169,23): warning CS0618: `System.Net.ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy' is obsolete:`Use ServerCertificateValidationCallback instead'*

*tlstest.cs(210,26): warning CS0618: `System.Net.Dns.Resolve(string)' is obsolete:`Use GetHostEntry instead'*

*tlstest.cs(176,11): warning CS0219: The variable `prefix' is assigned but its value is never used*

*Compilation succeeded - 3 warning(s)*

So now tlstest.exe has been created, so I ran:

```
mono tlstest.exe https://www.nuget.org //which returned an error:
```

*Error #-2146762486: CERT_E_CHAINING 0x800B010A*

Comment: Finding some answers here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/

Comment: Also if you are looking at TLS, checkout http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-s-new-TLS-provider-td4666825.html

Comment: looks like 
    **mozroots --import** 
wins this battle

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error "*Error #-2146762486: CERT_E_CHAINING 0x800B010A*". Followed the FAQ suggested by the link "mono-project.com/docs/faq/security" . 
Thanks to Jonathan James

Executed the command

```
"mozroots --import --ask-remove --machine"
```

**Below results displayed:**

> Mozilla Roots Importer - version 5.14.0.0 Download and import trusted
>   root certificates from Mozilla's MXR. Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus
>   Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.
>
> WARNING: mozroots is deprecated, please move to cert-sync instead.
>
> Downloading from 'https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-release/raw-file/default/security/nss/lib/ckfw/builtins/certdata.txt'...
>   WARNING: Downloading the trusted certificate list couldn't be done securely (error: RemoteCertificateChainErrors)

continuing anyway.

If you're using mozroots to bootstrap Mono's trust store on a clean system this might be OK, otherwise it could indicate a network intrusion. Please ensure you're using a trusted network or move to cert-sync.

> Importing certificates into machine store.
>   150 new root certificates were added to your trust store.
>   Import process completed.

Then did the below steps again:

```
csc tlstest.cs -r:System.dll <-- 2 warning as before
```

mono tlstest.exe https://www.nuget.org <--no error shown, only "https://www.nuget.org" is shown. 
Hope this helps...

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please edit your answer and format it better? Use backticks for `typewriter font` (\`) and \> for quotes. If you want some console output or text snippets indent them with four spaces at the very beginning of the line. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help